# How to plot Parametric plot from NDSolve solutions?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

So I used `NDSolve` to find the approximation for `y1` and `y2`, shown below.

```
a = 1;
b = -1; 
delta = 0.22;
f = 0.3;
eqs = { y1'[t] == y2[t], 
  y2'[t] == -b*y1[t] - delta*y2[t] - a*y1[t]^3 + f*Cos[y3[t]], 
  y3'[t] == 1, 
  y1[0] == 1, y2[0] == 0, y3[0] == 0 }
sol = NDSolve[eqs, {y1[t], y2[t]}, {t, 0, 200} ]
```

I'm now trying to plot `y2` vs `y1` but it doesn't work. Please help.

```
ParametricPlot[ {y2[t] /. sol, y1[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, 200} ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See the third example under "Basic Examples" of the docs for [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
ParametricPlot[{y2[t] /. sol[[1]], y1[t] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, 200}]
```

[image]

Comment: Or `ParametricPlot[{y2[t], y1[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 200}]`